# Custom accuracy metric over a range, for Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, regression

I need to write an accuracy metric (during training) that calculates accuracy % over a range. So it would show my custom accuracy every epoch during training.

For eg. If `y_pred` is 343 and y_target is `340`, and the range is `10`, it should be counted as correct. Meaning, any predicted value in the range `[340-5, 340+5]` would be counted as correct for that instance.

But the existing accuracy metric would consider the above to be wrong, and accuracy is very low for regression problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
y_pred = [125, 332, 268, 349]
y_target = [129, 342, 265, 370]

def accuracy(y_pred, y_target):
    a = [1 for i,j in zip(y_pred, y_target) if i in range(j-5,j+6)]

    return sum(a)/len(y_pred)

print(accuracy(y_pred, y_target))
```

Output:

```
0.5
```

Comment: I need to plug this in as an accuracy metric during training, so it shows my custom accuracy every epoch. So I'll be dealing with tensors. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Numpy

```
import numpy as np

...

good = np.abs(pred-target) <= (range/2)
```

would be a vector of booleans (`False` and `True`) telling you if the prediction is good enough.

Booleans in Python can be used as integers (with values respectively equal to `0` and `1`), and this implies that you can sum the `good` array to know how many predictions were on target

```
n_good = np.sum(good)
```

---

Small Benchmark

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...:  
   ...: target = np.ones(2**18, dtype=int)*10 
   ...: predicted = np.random.randint(0, 21, 2**18)                                       

In [2]: %timeit [1 for i,j in zip(predicted, target) if i in range(j-5,j+6)] 
   ...: %timeit sum(1 for i,j in zip(predicted, target) if i in range(j-5,j+6)) 
   ...: %timeit np.abs(predicted-target)<=5 
   ...: %timeit np.sum(np.abs(predicted-target)<=5)                                       
983 ms ± 6.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
964 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.63 ms ± 44.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.18 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]:
```